# FB.getLoginStatus not firing, why?

Tags: jquery, facebook

I'm been trying to figure out for a while... the callback is not hit.

I tried already to initialize again the FB instance... to switch on/off the sandbox mode and nothing happends... it feels like it is something simple I am missing, it is very frustating

any tips?

```
    $("#lkGetInfo").click(function () {
        alert(FB);

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            alert("C");
        });
        alert("D");
    });
```

Get Some Info

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out by myself, not very intuitive and not a lot of help out there.

If you have the same problem, it might be related to the app domain when you setup your app in facebook.

If you are working local like me, you want to  place http://loc.alhost on "site url field" and save.

After that place "loca.lhost" in the App Domain field and click in save, it will allow to be saved

run your getloginstatus callback and be happy

---

I place the dot in lo.cal because stackoverflow doesn't allow to place lo.cal name